# Set up a bluetooth DUN as HOST

Tags: bluetooth, reverse-tethering

I can't find instructions on how to make my Ubuntu share its internet connection through bluetooth.

The goal is to connect my Android smartphone to the Internet. My laptop is connected to the WiFi network. The router filters the devices and won't allow my phone to connect to it directly.

Any help would be much appreciated.